# Не подключаются не стандартные шрифты

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, шрифты

Ребят беда с подключением шрифтов, есть две одинаковые странички (хотя исходя из проблемы не совсем одинаковые) вот только первая подключает нужные шрифты а вторая нет, прилагаю два скрина как это выглядит в css

[image: Скрин 1]

[image: Скрин 2]

Ладно бы еще если это были бы две разные страницы, а так это можно сказать одна и та же только в разные периоды времени, пути к файлам не трогал все одинаково, подключал некоторые скрипты правда, но на конфликт стилей первым делом проверил. В чем может быть проблема даже не представляю.

Не думал что это имеет отношение к проблеме со шрифтами, но стараюсь рассматривать любые варианты, в общем никогда раньше с подобной ошибкой не сталкивался, может в ней дело? 
скрины прикрепляю

[image: скрин 3]
[image: скрин 4]

Comment: "пути к файлам не трогал все одинаково" - "не трогал" и "перепроверил" это два разных состояния, всё же) перепроверьте путь к файлу и его наличие по этому пути. ибо явно во втором варианте первый шрифт не находит и подключает второй.      "только в разные периоды времени" - уточните, что это значит. возможно, именно тут и закралась проблема недоступности шрифта в связи с этим состоянием страницы

Comment: Пути перепроверил, там все хорошо. А на счет разного периода времени: сверстал я эту страничку и сдал заказчику (в тот момент времени все работало как нужно), через некоторое время он ко мне снова обратился со своими правками (на тот момент он уже отредактировал макет согласно своим нуждам), я внес необходимые правки и после он указал мне на несоответствие шрифтам, но я сразу не обратил внимания как оказалось те исходники что он отправил мне на доработку уже имели это самое несоответствие шрифтам. Я понимаю что это не я сделал, но я хочу проблему решить или хотя бы понять откуда она взялась.

Comment: Резонно. Ну я бы начал всё жестко сверять (ваш рабочий предыдущий файл/архив и полученный нерабочий): сравнил бы файлы шрифтов в папке (название, размер), сравнил бы код подключения шрифтов (указание расширений, format('truetype'), запятые и прочие мелочи синтаксиса)...

Comment: Штудирую файлы на наличие ошибочного синтаксиса, но пока что безуспешно, добавил в тему еще возможные варианты, подскажите если вы имели дело с подобным.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте подключить шрифты через @font-face.
`@font-face {
  font-family: 'YanusC';
  src: url('../fonts/YanusC.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/YanusC.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url('../fonts/YanusC.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/YanusC.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/YanusC.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/yanusc.otf') format('opentype'),
       url('../fonts/YanusC.svg#YanusC') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}`
Воспользуйтесь сервисом https://onlinefontconverter.com/ по преобразованию шрифтов в разные форматы и подключайте их. Для каждого шрифта свой @font-face.

Answer (score 0):

Судя по тому что ошибка сетевая - вполне возможно что подключаешь шрифты извне. 
Попробуй скачать локально шрифты и jquery v.1.12 библиотеку и прописать локальный путь к ним.

Наблюдается та же ситуация, если использовать версии jquery ниже/выше?

Просьба отписаться по результатам.

Скинь, пожалуйста, код тега `<head></head>` сюда с ссылками на шрифты и jquery библиотеку.

Comment: Да, пробовал менять версии jquery (поведение ошибки без изменения) так и не понял причину ее возникновения, ну а проблему с подключением шрифтов решил простым подключением в head до этого они подключались через localStorage.

Comment: Константин, попробуйте подключить jquery без использования CDN ссылки. То есть, скачать в папку проекта и подключить в head.

Comment: Да я и не использовал CDN, всегда подключал jquery локально.

Comment: После подключения шрифтов в head ошибка со скриншотов осталась? Есди да, то проверьте скрипты ajax.

Comment: Также необходимо проверить возникает ли данная ошибка в разных браузерах или каком-то определенном, т.к. может быть ошибкой на подобии этой https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=321241 и относиться к браузеру, так и наподобии этой https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14683 и относиться к jquery. Дайте нам знать, пожалуйста, о результатах. Если есть вопросы - задавайте.